# Get attribute name from xml

Tags: bash, unix, grep, xmllint

I would like to filter example-below xml, using bash.

Problem:
If attribut of subnode att="t" exists, the attribut name should be print.

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<general>
    <node1>
        <subnode att1="a" att2="t" name="test"> </subnode>
        <subnode att1="a" name="test2"> </subnode>
        <subnode att1="a" name="test3"> </subnode>
        <subnode att1="a" att2="t" name="test4"> </subnode>
    </node1>
</general>
```

Output:

```
test
test4
```

I tried by grep and xmllint, but without success.

My "temporary" solution is:

```
xmllint --xpath 'string(//general/node1/subnode[@att2="t"]/@name)' file.xml
```

But the that command print only first occurrence - test.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite what you asked, but using perl (and an XML parser) both of which should be readily available on your system: (e.g. both should be available via package manager in most distros - `XML::Twig` can also be downloaded via `cpan` if you prefer)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->parse( \*DATA );

print $_->att('name'),"\n" for $twig->get_xpath('//subnode[@att2="t"]');

__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<general>
    <node1>
        <subnode att1="a" att2="t" name="test"> </subnode>
        <subnode att1="a" name="test2"> </subnode>
        <subnode att1="a" name="test3"> </subnode>
        <subnode att1="a" att2="t" name="test4"> </subnode>
    </node1>
</general>
```

As a one liner, this becomes:

```
perl -0777 -MXML::Twig -e 'print $_->att("name"),"\n" for XML::Twig->parse(<>)->get_xpath(q{//subnode[@att2="t"]})'
```

This one liner can be used in the same way as awk/sed/grep e.g. as a place to pipe the xml, or with file specified on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this works

```
awk '{if(/att[0-9]="t"/){line=$0;replacedLine=substr(line,index(line,"name="));gsub(/name="/,"",replacedLine);endIndex=index(replacedLine,"\"");print substr(replacedLine,0,endIndex);}}' xmlfile
```

Comment: I need the xml content for non working cases so that I can fix. Please update your question with few more cases. Also, my code assumes you want to match lines containing att[any_number]="t". Is it not so? you just need to match att2="t"?

Answer (score 0):

Use `xmlstarlet`:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//general/node1/subnode[@att2="t"]/@name' -nl
```

If you have to use `xmllint`, then do this:

```
 xmllint --xpath '//general/node1/subnode[@att2="t"]/@name' sample.xml \
     | sed 's/ name="//g; s/"/\n/g;'
```

Comment: xmlstarlet is not standard command... The best solution will be using xmllint.

Comment: By which you mean it's not on **your** system.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I would like use that command which one are on linux at all.

Comment: Generally, is better, and work pretty properly. But I have a lot of "XPath set is empty". And I can't filter it by grep etc. Strange.

Comment: Ok, I got it:  2>/dev/null